# null is not an object (evaluating 'CameraManger.Aspect') on android genymotion emulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to capture images using react-native.

I followed the below link to do this.

https://medium.com/@masochist.aman/capturing-images-with-react-native-203e24f93eb9.

I have installed all required pages. But I am getting above error. I googled to resolve this error. I got solution that, I need to execute the flowing commond "react-native link react-native-camera". But when I executed this commond it gives error that ,Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.

```
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Even though emulator is connected. Therefore, I am not getting where I am doing wrong.

If I unlink the react-native unlink react-native-camera it doesn't show the device connection error.
Therefore, anyone assist me to resolve this.

Comment: try running `adb devices` on cmd and check if genymotion emulator is online or not

Comment: @Firu, I have done this. Device is in online only.

Comment: Run `chmod 755 android/gradlew` inside your app root folder.

Comment: I am using Windows system

Comment: I think , chmod for Linux .